# How to display Catalog Price Rule Discount and Special Price Discount along with Cart Price Rule Discount?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, catalog-price-rules, magento2.2.4, special-price

I'm using Magento version 2.2.4.
Currently on view and edit checkout page, only Cart price rule discount is shown as below

[image]

How to show Catalog Price Rule and Special Price (added while adding a product in Admin panel) in same or another line on checkout index page?

Comment: It means you only need to show it as informative only. Am I guessing it right?

Comment: yes, just to inform customer what all discount(s) he is getting.